# How do I increase the resolution of a text object for use with a Shrinkwrap modifier?

Tags: modifiers, text-object

Guys can I give more resolution to the font without converting to a mesh so this kind of effect when used Shrinkwrap can be fixed?

[image]

Comment: if you convert it into a mesh you could use a Boolean to get the same effect

Comment: That´s the thing I cannot convert it need to be non destructive!